# Code Challange Joining repeated numbers on an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

my output from a machine learning algorithm is a list of segments, segments are represented by a pair of ids, each segment is part of a track(ideally, there are repeated ids and missing ids), and the following code produces a similar array:

```
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(42)
    #ids pairs are less the further you go on the track
    ids_ammount= np.arange(26,8,-2)
    # the array is a 2 column array  with conected segments
    ids_array = np.zeros((np.sum(ids_ammount),2))
    idx_0 = 0
    idx_1 = 0
    for i, ids in enumerate(ids_ammount):
      idx_1+=ids
      #first column is in order from smaller to largest id
      ids_array[:,0][idx_0:idx_1] = np.sort(np.random.randint(i * 10,10*(i+1),size=ids))
      ids_array[:,1][idx_0:idx_1] = np.random.randint((i + 1) * 10,10*(i+2),size=ids)
      idx_0+= ids
```

my goal is to reconstruct the tracks using **ids_array**, I have an implementation but is really inefficient with 3 **if** statements and I need to check manually the max number of repeated ids every time in order to make it work, so I prefer not to include it as I would like to get some fresh ideas on how to solve this as efficient as possible.
My desired output would be 9 arrays, one with ids that have just one connection, the other with 2 connections, and so on until 9 connections, example:

single_conection = [[0,18],[67,73]...],
double_conection = [[1,14,26], [53,68,79],....]
.
.
.
nine_conections = [[3,15,28,36,41,59,66,79,82,99]....]

Some of the problems that I encounter are, that ids are repeated, some ids don't exist, and the maximum number of repeated ids is variable.
If someone has an idea on how to reconstruct these tracks would be amazing, and if anyone knows how to do it efficiently would be even better.
Thanks

Comment: What's a connection? Please show a small input array and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the output. Please [edit] the question.

Comment: hey, the array that the above code produce would look something like this [[0,12],[0,17],[1,15].....[12,25], [15,28]....[25,32]], the desirded ouput in this case is: single_connection = [0,17], double_connection = [1,15,28], triple_connection  = [0,12,25,32] etc. So the ids are id of positions in certain layers, for layer 1 ids go from 0 to 9, layer 2 from 10 to 19 .... so a pair of ids in layer 1 is connected to a pair in layer 2, if  id in column 2 in layer 1 is the same as id in column 1 in layer 2. PS computer crashed just before finishing the answer thats why it was incomplete hehe

Comment: You have a graph where numbers represent vertices and pair of numbers represent edges. You want to find every path (which is not a part of a longer path). You want to learn some basics of graph theory and study graph algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any algorithm for merging intervals. The only difference is you need to check that the right border of left "interval" is equal to the left border of right "interval". [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/)